# How to access the Entity Manager inside of the KnpMenuBundle?

Tags: symfony

I am using the [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) and would like to access the Doctrine Entity Manager inside of the menu Builder class.  I want to check the database for some different values that might need to appear in the menu.  I tried passing the EM through a constructor but it doesn't work. What's the best way to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Here's the code I added to the Builder class:

```
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{

    $this->em = $em;


}
```

This throws an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to XXX\ThemeBundle\Menu\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in

Comment: Why it does not work? Did some error occur? Have you tried passing Doctrine object instead?

Comment: I just updated with the code and error.  Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to pass `EntityManager` as argument in constructor. If your `Builder` class extends `ContainerAware` class then you can access `EntityManager` object by adding following line in your  `*Menu` methods.

```
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to the service xml file:

```
<service id="app.menu_builder" class="AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder">
    <argument type="service" id="knp_menu.factory"/>
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
</service>
```

Add to your MenuBuilder class:

```
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory,EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->factory = $factory;
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must create your Menu class as service, then inject if needed the entired container, but you only need [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager] You can Read more about [menu as service](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_service.md)

Comment: injecting the whole container is a very bad practice